# LIKE condition for multiple rows

Tags: sql

I have a table in Oracle DB where it has two column:

```
Area                Service Request Count
-------            ------------------------

e-life-first                5
e-life-second               3
Tariff                      1
Disconnect                  2
LTE-1                       9
LTE2                        10
```

I have a query to select all the proper tables...
but I need to put a WHERE condition to select Any Thing "LIKE" e-life & "LIKE" LTE ONLY!

so the result must be:

```
Area                Service Request Count
-------            ------------------------

e-life-first                5
e-life-second               3
LTE-1                       9
LTE2                        10
```

Please Support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `%` wild card. For performance only add the wildcard on the end like so:

```
WHERE (Area LIKE 'e-life%' OR Area LIKE 'LTE%')
```

Edit: Added parentheses per HLGEM's comment.

Comment: I do suggest alawys using parentheses around an OR condition to make it clear what is grouped together in the OR even when it is the only condition. This prevents inadvertent incorrect results (due to order of operations) later when people add other conditions to the query.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WHERE Area LIKE '%e-life%' OR Area LIKE '%LTE%'
```

Comment: that should be an `OR` not an `AND`.

Comment: There is no need for the wildcard at the beginning of both checks.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT <columns to return>
FROM <table name>
WHERE Area LIKE '%e-life%'
OR Area LIKE '%LTE%'
```

That should return all rows where Area contains e-life or LTE

Answer (score 0):

If "e-life" or "LTE" can appear anywhere in the string you should use:

```
WHERE Area Like '%e-life%' OR Areal Like '%LTE%'
```

However, if "e-life" or "LTE" will always appear at the beginning of the string you can use:

```
WHERE Area Like 'e-life%' OR Areal Like 'LTE%'
```

or if "e-life" or "LTE" will always appear at the beginning of the string and Area is indexed you can use this which will preform much faster than either of the two above options:

```
SELECT
    ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE Area Like 'e-life%'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE Area Like 'LTE%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an OR:

```
WHERE area LIKE 'e-life%' OR area LIKE 'LTE%'
```